# call a service from a service and return its result

Tags: angular, service, observable

I wrote a service that collects some data and assembles an object. This service then calls another service (which calls an API using HTTPClient) and returns the ID of a ressource it just created. This basically works and looks quite "normal":

(omitted some lines)

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class CourseWizardService {
  // Page Data
  (...)

  constructor(
    private courseService: CourseService) { }
```

in a function of that service I call another one and receive the result:

```
// assemble step data to final object then call creation API & return new Id (to navigate)
  finish() {
    const newCourse = CourseFactory.empty();

    // set values
    (...)


    // ToDO: notify caller about new ID
    this.courseService.addCourse(newCourse).subscribe(courseId => {
      ??RETURN?? = courseId;
      this.reset();
    });

  }
```

my goal is to return the "courseId" from the finish() function to the "outer" caller (a component) so i can navigate with the router to that new ressource. But I'm running into some "syncing-problem" when I change the function to finish(): number and return that id.

I'm not an expert for observables, could it be that I have to create a new observable - maybe using of() - and "submit" the original observable to the caller?

This what I want to do in the component:

```
// finish: save item
this.courseWizardService.finish();

// receive/pass-through the ID so I can navigate
this.router.navigate(['/home']);
```

**UPDATE**
I don't know how to actually pass the "courseId" (result of the API) from the calling service to the component.

```
(CourseWizardService)

finish() {
    // (...)
    return this.courseService.addCourse(newCourse).pipe(
      tap(courseId => { // how to pass that over?
        this.reset();
    }));
}


(Component)

onSubmit() {
    this.courseWizardService.finish().pipe(
      take(1)
      ).subscribe(() => this.router.navigate(['courses', courseId])); // where would "courseId" come from?
}
```

Comment: *What* "syncing-problem"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use observable to return the finish call.

```
finish() {
    ...
    return this.courseService.addCourse(newCourse).pipe(
      tap(courseId => {
        ??RETURN?? = courseId;
        this.reset();
    }));
}
```

And in your active service:

```
this.courseWizardService.finish().pipe(take(1)).subscribe(() =>
  this.router.navigate(['/home']);
, err => {
  // ...some error debug here
});
```

Comment: Could you please give me some more guidance? I'm struggling and I don't know how to return the courseId to start the navigation on the caller-side. I'm updating the question since I can't seem to write here formatted.

Comment: n/m - figoured it out, it's quite easy :-) Thanks.